# random error when trying to delete blog from drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-content-types

This is the error I get when trying to delete page i am also trying to see if the page/blogs are on the ftp but cant seem to find it all i want to do is delete this one page but wont let me as this error always comes up

Also it doesn't let me delete pictures of this page/blog or description

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'thumbnailfid' in 'where clause': DELETE FROM {video_thumbnails} WHERE (thumbnailfid = :db_condition_placeholder_0) ; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => 614 ) in video_file_delete() (line 280 of /var/www/vhosts/themeissenman.com/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/video/video.module).

Answer (score 0):

try to re-enable video module ..

OR

run update.php

Comment: i just done all updates and downloads now this comes up when using /update.php at the end process (Run updates):         PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'meissen.media_filter_usage' doesn't exist: DELETE FROM {media_filter_usage} WHERE (timestamp < :db_condition_placeholder_0) ; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => 1381685938 ) in media_flush_caches() (line 1129 of /var/www/vhosts/themeissenman.com/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/media/media.module) ...i cant do anymore then that wont let me do a full update the is a strange error i appreciate any help